# How hide fields when using include filter

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, loopback4

I'm unable to hide specific fields whenever I use `include` in the filter. For example the following filter suppose to hide `listId` and `list_id` fields but it doesn't!

```
const filter = {
      where: {color: colorStr},
      include: [{relation: 'todos'}],
      fields: {"listId": false, "list_id": false}, //FIXME: Unable to hide these two fields
    }
```

The output is:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0",
    "title": "Home",
    "desc": "string",
    "color": 45,
    "status": 0,
    "todos": [
      {
        "id": "077b38f8-9bb6-41f1-aba5-fadae4ca98b3",
        "title": "Iron the t-shirt",
        "desc": null,
        "staus": 2,
        "listId": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0",
        "list_id": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0"
      },
      {
        "id": "26bb6473-fbd8-462d-92e6-efcb4a8de734",
        "title": "Clean the table",
        "desc": "string",
        "staus": 0,
        "listId": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0",
        "list_id": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0"
      },
      {
        "id": "9664d74f-f146-4b57-b34e-1bc668a063b6",
        "title": "Fıx the chaır",
        "desc": null,
        "staus": 2,
        "listId": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0",
        "list_id": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0"
      },
      {
        "id": "b8bde42b-182c-48aa-9597-a1da9961ea97",
        "title": "Fiixo",
        "desc": null,
        "staus": 4,
        "listId": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0",
        "list_id": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your filter would work if the fields you want to hide were adjacent to `todos` and not sub-fields in the todo´s array.

An alternative filter where you specify what to include, rather than what to exclude, might work:

```
const filter = {
  where: { color: colorStr },
  include: [
    {
      relation: 'todos',
      scope: {
        fields: ['id', 'title', 'desc', 'status'],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian I tried this filter but I get:
`error TS2345: Argument of type '{ where: { color: string; }; include: { relation: string; scope: { fields: string[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<Lists>'.
  Types of property 'include' are incompatible.
    Type '{ relation: string; scope: { fields: string[]; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Inclusion[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.`

Comment: My bad, include should be an array. I updated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work; I no longer able to get `todos` the output `[
  {
    "id": "90caa22d-3d16-4d5f-9e15-13dd978a62a0",
    "title": "Home",
    "desc": "string",
    "color": 45,
    "status": 0
  }
]`

Answer (score 0):

`scope` applies only at the "root" of the filter object. Hence, we'll need to craft the filter using the dot-delimited syntax:

```js
// Due to a limitation with TypeScript types, we need to silence the compiler for this line.
// @ts-ignore
const filter: Filter<MyModel> = {
  where: {color: colorStr},
  include: [{relation: 'todos'}],
  fields: [
    'todos',
    'todos.listId',
    'todos.list_id',
  ],
};
```

### References

- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5244#issuecomment-679139313

Comment: I get an empty response `[  {}]` Do I miss anything?
I replaced `Filter<MyModel>` with my real model `Filter<Lists>`
I tried to run `Filter<MyModel>` but I get a similar result.